# StackOverflow in ScriptBundle .NET VS2013

Tags: javascript, c#, scriptbundle

We are experiencing a StackOverflow exception in VS2013 using:

```
var importedTypesBundle = new ScriptBundle("~/ImportedTypes/all.js");
```

Replacing with Bundle() it works... but it does not minify.

It looks the mifinier is not happy about some js file. Any idea how find the error source?

Comment: You could try catching first chance exceptions in Visual Studio after you restart the app pool and when the bundle is requested for the first time.

Comment: actually the exception is: An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in WebGrease.dll and it stops in our _Layout.cshtml at line:     @Scripts.Render("~/ImportedTypes/all.js")

Comment: @Robert, did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Comment: Finally we moved to gulp bundling that give us a lot of feature including minify